# How to apply different settings when swtiching between Windows and WSL?

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

for example, I'm using CMake to build. But the toolchain arg is configured in setting.json, so when I switch to WSL from Windows, I have to change the directory so that CMake can find the right toolchain file.

```
"cmake.configureArgs": [
    // "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/isudfv/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
    "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\\Program Files\\Vcpkg\\scripts\\buildsystems\\vcpkg.cmake",
    "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [project_options](https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/project_options/), which automatically installs vcpkg in a cross-platform way.

To do this manually, install vcpkg in an os-agnostic path like `~/vcpkg`.